# Yii2 защита от race condition

Tags: php, yii2, yii, безопасность, race-condition

Как в `Yii2` можно обезопасить свой код от атаки типа `race condition`?

Например, в `Laravel` для `SQL` запросов есть такая штука как `pessimistic locking` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#pessimistic-locking), которая блокирует данные от модификации до окончания транзакции.

Как в этом плане обстоят дела с `ActiveQuery`? Понятно, что `PHP` из коробки ставит все запросы для одной сессии в очередь (https://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/blokirovanie-sessiy-v-php), но пользователь может зайти с разных браузеров под своими учетными данными, тем самым запустив несколько сессий.

Поэтому вопрос - как защищаться от атак `race condition` в `Yii2` при использовании `ActiveQuery`?

Comment: транзакции не помогут? + уровень изоляции транзакции  (https://unetway.com/tutorial/yii-database-access-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Загуглите про блокировки в вашей базе данных по запросу "mysql locks", например. Вы очень быстро обнаружите конструкцию `select ... for update|share` -- это блокировка выбранных строк в транзакции до завершения этой транзакции. То есть, когда вы делаете select for update строк, которые собираетесь менять, другие транзакции не смогут сделать select for update и update этих строк и будут ждать до завершения первой транзакции. Это функционал sql баз данных, поддерживающих транзакции, вы можете использовать его с любым фрэймворком и с нативным php. Методы lockForUpdate и sharedLock, на которые вы ссылаетесь, просто обёртка для этого функционала базы.

Теперь вам остаётся нагуглить как делать select for update в Yii2. В общем случае вам надо просто добавить к select-запросу `for update` и выполнять его в одной транзакции с запросом на обновление. Этот метод решает проблему с гонкой при обновлении данных в базе (кажется то, что вам нужно).

Comment: забыли только уточнить версию mysql - это расширение запроса добавили только в 8ке

Comment: @WinterSilence нет. Например вот [дока по 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html).

Answer (score 0):

yii2 оптимистичнее :) см. `yii\db\ActiveRecord::optimisticLock()`, подробности в [руководстве](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/db-active-record#optimistic-locks)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/717142)

Comment: @Dmitry если страница официального мануала будет изменена, то моя копипаста оттуда окажется не актуальной